# Coldfusion 11 install successful but service wont start

Tags: windows, coldfusion, installation, adobe

I downloaded the latest coldfusion 64bit for windows yesterday, file `ColdFusion_11_WWEJ_win64.exe`, and it completed installation successfully on my windows 7 professional machine. The Cold Fusion Application Server service did not start and trying to start it via services results in a 1053 error immediately. There are no log files generated at this point.

I have tried installing 4 times with various options. I am using apache for the web server, which works fine with coldfusion 9. I tried the hotfix patch 4 for cf 11, which was mentioned in another post. It installed properly but had no effect. I also checked the xml file `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\runtime\conf\context.xml` to make sure that

`<Manager pathname=""/>` was not commented out (and it wasn't), which was mentioned in an adobe blog post.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the service running?

Comment: Try starting it from the command line and seeing what kinds of messages it gives

Answer (score 0):

If the service is not starting, there could likely be a problem at ColdFusion end. Please try the following:–

1. Stop ColdFusion service
2. Launch Command prompt as Administrator
3. Browse to cf_root\cfusion\bin and run the following command
   **coldfusion.exe -start console**
4. Try to access the CF admin, once the services are started.

In case it gives an error message, please share the same.